# Efficient way to abstract multidimensional ArrayList to Collection

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, superclass, abstraction

I have a class that returns an ArrayList of ArrayLists. I would like to return a Collection of Collections to abstract the output datatype.

With a standard ArrayList, its easy - just define the return type as Collection. Unfortunately, with a 2D ArrayList, that doesn't work:

```
//This does not compile
public Collection<Collection<Object> myFunction() {
  return new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
}

//This does compile (but isn't what I want)
public Collection<ArrayList<Object> myFunction() {
  return new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
}
```

Obviously one can create a Collection, then add the ArrayLists individually, converting them to Collections, but this is more complicated than I would expect. What is the proper way to abstract a multidimensional return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously one can create a Collection, then add the ArrayLists individually, converting them to Collections, but this is more complicated than I would expect. What is the proper way to abstract a multidimensional return type?

That's not how it works. ArrayLists **are** a collection. That's what `class Dog extends Animal` means: All dogs already are animals. There is no 'converting'. You don't convert a dog to an animal, it's already one.

Hence, *add the ArrayLists individually, converting them to Collections* is nonsense.

> ```java
> // paraphrased
> ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
> Collection<Collection<Object>> b = a;
> ```

no, this does not compile, because that is a nonsensical statement. The thing is, collections have an `add` method. You can add things to them. And java is a reference-based system, so in the code above there is only a single list-of-lists (count the `new` - I only count one, so there must be only one list here, there cannot possibly be 2), just.. you have 2  variables pointing at the same thing. Like an address book with 2 pages, both with the same address on it.

Via variable `b` I could do: `b.add(new HashSet<Object>())`. That should be obvious: All HashSets **are** collections, the `.add()` method of variable `b` requires a `Collection<Object>`, and.. `new HashSet<Object>()` **is** a `Collection<Object>`, therefore, that is allowed. And indeed that is valid java here.

Except.. it's the same list. `a` **also** points at this list. Which.. now has a HashSet in it. A variable of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` has.. a HashSet in it.

Oh dear.

That's all wrong.

Which is why java does not allow `Collection<Collection<Object>> b = a;` here - because **that is nonsense**.

You can opt into covariance by writing:

```
Collection<? extends Collection<?>> b = a;
```

This is not too useful - the point of `?` here is to stop you from calling 'add', and then all is well. This assignment works, and indeed `b.add(new HashSet<>())` no longer works now, but, `b.get(0).add(someObject)` also no longer works.

The correct move is to go to where-ever you make that initial arraylist and make it correct right from the get-go: Make that a `new ArrayList<Collection<Object>>`. Because all ArrayLists **are** collections, you can call `.add(new ArrayList<Object>())` on a variable of type `ArrayList<Collection<Object>>`, no problem. And you can assign an `ArrayList<Collection<Object>>` to a variable of type `Collection<Collection<Object>>`.

Generics are invariant - if you need type FourFootedAnimal, only that type will do. You can't provide a subtype or a supertype. But outside of generics, java is covariant - FourFootedAnimals will do, but so will a Dog or a Cat. If you want covariance, use `? extends` (and `?` on its own is short for `? extends Object`), but note that this **disables** all attempts to add.

Comment: Of course, `b.get(0).add(someObject)` can’t work as widening the `List` to `Collection` makes the `get(int)` method unavailable. You’d have to use `b.iterator().next().add("some object");` and when you change the declaration of `b` to `Collection<? extends Collection<Object>> b = a;`, it does work. An alternative is `Collection<Collection<Object>> b = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(a);` since this also prevents adding wrong elements (at runtime), it allows widening the element type even without wildcards.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, thanks for the explanation. I didn't think of the reference issue, which makes this impossible to perform with a simple assignment operation. I was able to adjust the original ArrayList in this instance, and it is a much better solution than covariance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Collection<Collection<Object>>` as your return type, you can use `Collection<? extends Collection<Object>>`. This syntax asserts that you will be returning a `Collection` of something that implements the `Collection` interface, which allows you to call any methods specified by the `Collection` interface, without assuming anything more specific.

```java
public Collection<? extends Collection<Object>> myFunction() {
    return new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
}
```

You can read more about why this happens in the Oracle's page on [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html), and on [Wildcards and Subtyping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)